# Increase message buffer size for boost::beast wrapper of unix domain socket

Tags: c++, sockets, boost

I’m using the `boost::beast` wrapper of unix domain socket. my platform is macOS.

First, I define the socket :

```
boost::asio::local::stream_protocol::socket socket;
```

I’d like to use it to read messages sized up to 2k.

```
boost::asio::streambuf input_streambuf;
...
boost::asio::async_read(socket, input_streambuf,
                        boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1), yield);
```

However, the input_streambuf is only 512 bytes.

Any idea if I can increase this limit from Boost::beast ? or perhaps it's some definition in the system level ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any Beast types here. It's all exclusively Asio.

Also, `streambuf` models the `DynamicBuffer` concept. It has no fixed size, so your claim is not accurate.

Finally, no matter how big the initial capacity of the `streambuf` were to be, it won't do you much good because you instruct the `async_read` to `transfer_at_least(1)`, which means that any platform-dependent buffer in the underlying implementations will probably cause the first `read_some` to return much smaller quantity. E.g. with this simple server:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbf0a1d585ebcc8e)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace net = boost::asio;
using U = net::local::stream_protocol;

int main() {
    net::thread_pool io;
    using net::yield_context;

    U::acceptor acc(io, "./test.sock");
    acc.listen();
    U::socket s = acc.accept();

    spawn(io, [&](yield_context yield) { //
        net::streambuf buf;
        while (auto n = async_read(s, buf, net::transfer_at_least(1), yield))
            std::cout << "Read: " << n << " (cumulative: " << buf.size() << ")"
                      << std::endl;
    });

    io.join();
}
```

When using a client like e.g.:

```
netcat -U ./test.sock <<RESP
   Hello world
   This is Brussels calling
   From pool to pool
   RESP
```

Will print e.g.: [image]

```
Read: 55 (cumulative: 55)
```

But when running `netcat -U ./test.sock` interactively: [image]

```
Read: 12 (cumulative: 12)
Read: 30 (cumulative: 42)
Read: 17 (cumulative: 59)
```

In fact, we can quite literally throw a thousand dictionaries at it:

```
for a in {1..1000}; do cat /etc/dictionaries-common/words; done | netcat -U ./test.sock
```

And the output is:

```
Read: 512 (cumulative: 512)
Read: 512 (cumulative: 1024)
Read: 512 (cumulative: 1536)
Read: 512 (cumulative: 2048)
Read: 512 (cumulative: 2560)
Read: 1536 (cumulative: 4096)
Read: 512 (cumulative: 4608)
Read: 3584 (cumulative: 8192)
Read: 512 (cumulative: 8704)
Read: 7680 (cumulative: 16384)
Read: 512 (cumulative: 16896)
Read: 15872 (cumulative: 32768)
Read: 512 (cumulative: 33280)
Read: 32256 (cumulative: 65536)
Read: 512 (cumulative: 66048)
Read: 65024 (cumulative: 131072)
Read: 512 (cumulative: 131584)
Read: 65536 (cumulative: 197120)
...
Read: 49152 (cumulative: 971409238)
Read: 49152 (cumulative: 971458390)
Read: 49152 (cumulative: 971507542)
Read: 49152 (cumulative: 971556694)
Read: 21306 (cumulative: 971578000)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::wrapexcept<boost::exception_detail::current_exception_std_exception_wrapper<std::runtime_error> >'
  what():  End of file [asio.misc:2]
```

As you can see, the size of the buffer is dependent on the OS, which actually does a decent job of scaling it up to requirements.

### Improving The Instructions

So, instead of `transfer_at_least` use whatever minimum you found reasonable:

```
while (auto n = async_read(s, buf, net::transfer_at_least(1024*1024), yield))
    std::cout << "Read: " << n << " (cumulative: " << buf.size() << ")"
              << std::endl;
```

Prints instead:

```
Read: 1048576 (cumulative: 1048576)
Read: 1048576 (cumulative: 2097152)
Read: 1063342 (cumulative: 3160494)
Read: 1086266 (cumulative: 4246760)
...
Read: 1086266 (cumulative: 969962524)
Read: 1102650 (cumulative: 971065174)
```

Or if you are content to read until EOF:

```
while (auto n = async_read(s, buf, yield[ec])) {
    std::cout << ec.message() << ": " << n
              << " (cumulative: " << buf.size() << ")" << std::endl;
    if (ec.failed())
        break;
}
```

Note that subtly we added error_code checking so we don't miss the whole transfer due to EOF. Now prints:

```
End of file: 971578000 (cumulative: 971578000)
```

Finally, you may want to limit maximum capacity, say to 50 Mib:

```
constexpr size_t _50MiB = 50<<20;
net::streambuf buf(_50MiB);

boost::system::error_code ec;
while (auto n = async_read(s, buf, yield[ec])) {
    std::cout << ec.message() << ": " << n
              << " (cumulative: " << buf.size() << ")" << std::endl;
    if (ec.failed())
        break;
}
if (ec != net::error::eof && buf.size() == _50MiB) {
    std::cout << "Warning: message truncated" << std::endl;
}
```

Now we can't force feed dictionaries to run us out of memory:

```
Success: 52428800 (cumulative: 52428800)
Warning: message truncated
```

Comment: Added some alternative approaches that get you different transfer "units". Also, how to read "indefinitely" and finally, how to protect against malice/run-away data by setting a limit.